Rotate latex tikz figure
I would like to rotate the following latex figure to have the violin vertical (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/662974/how-can-i-make-a-violin-plot-in-pgfplots):
\begin{filecontents*}{data1.dat}
5   1
6   1
3   1
3   1
7   1
8   1
3   1
8   1
7   1
9   1
5   1
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{data2.dat}
12  2
14  2
12  2
8   2
22  2
22  2
12  2
12  2
7   2
12  2
2   2
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{data3.dat}
20  3
20  3
21  3
20  3
22  3
21  3
20  3
24  3
22  3
21  3
20  3
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, xmax=25,
ymin=0, ymax=4,
ytick={1,2,3},
yticklabels={Condition 1, Condition 2, Condition 3},
]
\addplot[draw=none] gnuplot[raw gnuplot] {
plot 0; %included to avoid warning of empty plot
set table "kdensity1.dat";
plot "data1.dat" using 1:2 smooth kdensity bandwidth 1.;
unset table;
set table "kdensity2.dat";
plot "data2.dat" using 1:2 smooth kdensity bandwidth 1.;
unset table;
set table "kdensity3.dat";
plot "data3.dat" using 1:2 smooth kdensity bandwidth 1.;
unset table;
};

\addplot[draw=none, name path=p1, y filter/.expression={1+0.1*y}] table {kdensity1.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path=m1, y filter/.expression={1-0.1*y}] table {kdensity1.dat};
\addplot[red!50] fill between [of=p1 and m1];

\addplot[draw=none, name path=p2, y filter/.expression={2+0.1*y}] table {kdensity2.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path=m2, y filter/.expression={2-0.1*y}] table {kdensity2.dat};
\addplot[green!50] fill between [of=p2 and m2];

\addplot[draw=none, name path=p3, y filter/.expression={3+0.1*y}] table {kdensity3.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path=m3, y filter/.expression={3-0.1*y}] table {kdensity3.dat};
\addplot[blue!50] fill between [of=p3 and m3];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I have tried using a scope (https://tikz.dev/tikz-transformations) as follows, but it also changes the shape:
\begin{scope}[xslant=-1,yslant=-1]
\end{scope}

Would you please have any advice to change the direction of the violins?

Try this \rotatebox{90}{ your figure}
